# Admin interface styles sometimes missing; frontend CSS loaded

Tags: 7, theming

Using administration pages on an old Drupal 7 installation, the "normal" admin CSS styles are sometimes gone and the page appears with the frontend layout.

After reloading the page, the normal admin CSS is back.

What could cause this problems, and how could I fix them?

## Screenshots

Frontend layout mixed into admin page:
[image: Frontend layout mixed into admin page]

Correct admin layout:
[image: Correct admin layout]

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console when styles don't load?

Comment: No. Comparing the included CSS files shows that instead of `adminimal_theme` CSS files, the frontend theme files get included.

Comment: How do you load your frontend css files and where are they placed in the folder structure?

Comment: CSS files are loaded via the theme's `.info` file, e.g. `stylesheets[all][] = stylesheets/logged-in.css` and are in the theme folder: `sites/all/themes/mytheme/stylesheets/logged-in.css`